# Show that the group of nth roots of unity under multiplication is isomorphic to the integers modulo n.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that the group $H_n = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z^n = 1\} = \{e^{2ik\pi} : k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ ($n^{th}$ roots of unity) under multiplication is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Preferably with reference to the universal property of surjective homomorphisms.

In attempting to prove the statement above, I found that it is obvious the order of the two groups is the same. With that, I found it to be somewhat obvious that there is a bijection between the two groups with a defined function $\varphi$. I proved the statement without showing explicitly that there is a bijection but more so since there is a homomorphism if we define $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_n \to H_n$ as $\varphi(x) = e^{2ix\pi}$ and just kind of accepting that there is clearly a bijection. Probably not a smart way to prove the statement since showing the bijection is certainly important.

In summary, what I am looking for (or guidance to) is a way to prove the statement from the universal property of surjective homomorphisms and to show the bijection is there.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $e^{2ikn\pi}\cdot e^{2iln\pi} = e^{2i(k+l)n\pi}$. Since $e^{2in\pi} = e^{2i0\pi}=1$, the addition in the exponent is the same as the addition of integers mod $n$.

This gives an isomorphism $\Bbb Z_n\rightarrow H_n:k\mapsto e^{2ikn\pi}$.

Let $k=qn+r$ with $0\leq r<n$ (remainder mod $n$). Then $e^{2ikn\pi} = e^{2irn\pi}$.

Comment: That’s what I arrived at in my proof. I just don’t see the application of the universal property of surjective homs. I don’t know, maybe it’s just going over my head, I’m unsure.

Comment: See added comment: integer division with remainder.

Comment: How could this shows surjectivity? I did not understand

Answer (score 1):

Proving ${H_n \mapsto Z_n}$ is surjective. we have ${f(x)= e^{xp}, where, p=i \cdot (2\pi/n)}$

- ${f(x)=y=e^{xp}}$ , then ${ln(y)=xp}$ , this implies  ${x=(1/p)\cdot ln(y)}$
- then ${f(x)= f((1/p)\cdot ln(y))  }$  ${\Rightarrow}$  ${f(x) = e^{(1/p)\cdot p \cdot ln(y)}}$  ${\Rightarrow}$  ${f(x)=y}$,
- this shows that for every y in codomain has some x in domain. i.e, function is surjective.
- so function is injective (proved above) and surjective , i.e., bijective, hence isomorphic.
- You can also prove first function is homomorphic and then prove bijection.

Comment: It may be a bit late... But I think you defined function in a wrong way is not it? I think it should be $\mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow H_n$

Comment: To rigorously show that $x = (1/p) \cdot ln(y) \in \mathbb{Z}\Big/{n\mathbb{Z}}$, it's necessary to recall the definition of $n$-th complex root, that is, it exist $x' \in \mathbb{Z}\Big/{n\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $y = e^i{\frac{2\pi x'}{n}}$ and because $f$ is inyective, $x = x'$, showing that $x \in \mathbb{Z}\Big/{n\mathbb{Z}}$.